# Obtain a HTML elements hidden value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML element like so:

```
<select>
   <option id="a" hidden"1">Abcdefgh</option
</select>
```

**And, using javascript, I want to retreive the hidden value from the option element.**

How do I do this?

```
var hiddenVal = document.getElementById( "a" ).hidden; // this doesnt work
```

Comment: You're missing an assignment operator... and I don't think `hidden` is a property of `option`.

Comment: Agreed, maybe you'd be better off using the `data-*` attribute instead?

Comment: Andrew is spot on here, custom attributes are not supported in HTML 4 and in 5 they are as data-* (* being whatever you want to call it)

Answer (score 2):

Not all attributes map directly to properties. You should be able to use the native `.getAttribute()` to get the value of custom attributes.

```
var hiddenVal = document.getElementById( "a" ).getAttribute('hidden');
```

```
<select>
   <option id="a" hidden="1">Abcdefgh</option>
</select>
```

Comment: beat me to it, was caught up adding links to [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) and [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/value) for both solutions.

Comment: @Brad: Thanks for adding the links. I'm getting too lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off your mark up on your HTMl is all off. You are missing an end tag on the  element and you would need to put hidden="1" with the equals and quotes. But is hidden even a valid attribute for an option element?? I dont think it is.

Comment: Why would you vote me down? because i made a correct assessment...lame.

Comment: Voting down should be reserved for incorrect or misleading answers; this was neither and a down vote is inappropriate.